# how to forward url containing certain directory to same url on new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Just launched a new site. Kept the old site, but assigned it to a subdomain.

I need to forward requests for old site URLs to the new subdomain.

Old site URLs all have this structure: "www.oldsite.com/BMT/xxxxxx" where the "/BMT/" directly follows the .com.

I need my .htaccess to forward URLs like that to "subdomain.oldsite.com" instead of "www.oldsite.com", keeping the same path after the "/BMT/"

Any URLs without the "/BMT/" should not be redirected.

From my research, I think this might work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/BMT http://subdomain.oldsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Am I on the right track?

If so, where should I add it in my current .htaccess?

Current .htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/BMT [NC]
```

is a condition ,if it matchs the request uri string starting with /BMT then the rule will redirect the uri to http://sub.domain .

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/BMT [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.oldsite.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Perfect! I assume omitting the [NC] would make the condition case sensitive?